# yii2 query takes too much time to load data

Tags: mysql, yii2

```
 $query = IroningOrder::find()->alias("io")->select(["io.*", "u1.username as createdByUser", "u2.username as updatedByUser", "concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name", "CONCAT(ud1.first_name , ' ', ud1.last_name) as pickedUpBy", "CONCAT(ud2.first_name , ' ', ud2.last_name) as deliveredBy", "ioe3.updated_at as delivered_at"])
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "user u1", "u1.id = io.created_by")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "user u2", "u2.id = io.updated_by")
                ->join("INNER JOIN", "tbl_customer c", "c.id = io.customer_id")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation ioe1", "ioe1.ironing_order_id = io.id")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation ioe2", "ioe2.ironing_order_id = io.id")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation ioe3", "ioe3.ironing_order_id = io.id AND ioe3.type = 'DELIVERY' AND io.delivery_status = 'COMPLETE'")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_user_details ud1", "ud1.user_id = ioe1.user_id AND ioe1.type = 'PICKUP'")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_user_details ud2", "ud2.user_id = ioe2.user_id AND ioe2.type = 'DELIVERY'")
                ->join("LEFT JOIN", "tbl_delivery_address da", "da.id = io.delivery_address_id")
                ->groupBy(["io.id"]);


    SELECT `io`.`id`, `io`.`customer_id`, `io`.`status`, `io`.`pickup_status`, `io`.`allocated_bag_id`, `io`.`inward_status`, `io`.`outward_status`, `io`.`ironman_status`, `io`.`created_at`, `io`.`updated_at`, `io`.`delivery_status`, `u1`.`username` AS `createdByUser`, `io`.`total`, `u2`.`username` AS `updatedByUser`, concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name, CONCAT(ud1.first_name , ' ', ud1.last_name) as pickedUpBy, CONCAT(ud2.first_name , ' ', ud2.last_name) as deliveredBy, `ioe3`.`updated_at` AS `delivered_at` 
FROM `tbl_ironing_order` `io` 
LEFT JOIN `user` `u1` ON u1.id = io.created_by 
LEFT JOIN `user` `u2` ON u2.id = io.updated_by 
INNER JOIN `tbl_customer` `c` ON c.id = io.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation` `ioe1` ON ioe1.ironing_order_id = io.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation` `ioe2` ON ioe2.ironing_order_id = io.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_ironing_order_emp_allocation` `ioe3` ON ioe3.ironing_order_id = io.id AND ioe3.type = 'DELIVERY' AND io.delivery_status = 'COMPLETE' LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_details` `ud1` ON ud1.user_id = ioe1.user_id AND ioe1.type = 'PICKUP' 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_details` `ud2` ON ud2.user_id = ioe2.user_id AND ioe2.type = 'DELIVERY' 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_delivery_address` `da` ON da.id = io.delivery_address_id GROUP BY `io`.`id`
```

When i run this query it will give me proper result set,But it will take too much time to load page.Please help me to optimize above query

Comment: I think that it could be related to sql performance. Have you added some indexes to column field (database)?

Comment: Once you have verified  proper indexing on all the tables involved .. for so complex  relation if you really need  good performance you could avoid  the activeRecord and use direct sql based createCommand

Comment: activeRecord task much time the command query so i suggest you to use sql or create some store procedure and then call that procedure it will improve you performance.

Comment: Use MySQL EXPLAIN for the SELECT query to find out where it is taking more time and also implement INDEX if your database tables have more records. Please refer this link to understand about EXPLAIN - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: please check mysql query